# css for wrapping one image and several links inside that image

Tags: css

i have seen several websites which does this including weheartit.com,tumblr flipkart .

when we place cursor on images it shows several additional links like comment,share,like etc however when that image is clicked it takes to some other links.

here are few links which i am interested if anyone can guide for this type of css formatting it will be a great help.

place ur mouse on any of the offers like electronic offers etc you can see share image will come over images

```
    http://www.flipkart.com/offers?otracker=hp_widget_banner_0_image
```

go to any image you will see nice css effects and details will appear once the cursor goes above images here

```
      http://weheartit.com/?page=1
```

please give sample example with one image atleast

Comment: Use your browser's element inspection tools to analyze how they do it, it's pretty simple just have a container with `position:relative` and the content you want to appear with `position:absolute`

Comment: "please give sample" doesn't fly well here as SO when you haven't shown any effort to solve it yourself. See [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [**this**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/) out. The concept is called `mouse over/hover effects`, You can search on Google and find many similiar examples.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example from [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/):

[**Slide-in Captions**](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SlideinCaptions/)

Answer (score 0):

You should find the code within the example sites you provided in your description. For the site http://www.flipkart.com/offers?otracker=hp_widget_banner_0_image , the name of the div that contains the share contents is `sharebox`.

The CSS file that contains the styling and CSS effects for `sharebox` is the following:
http://img6a.flixcart.com/www/prod/lego-da812168-nogz.css

Search that for sharebox and try to figure out how they do it.